# Unable to Download Latest Version of DBX

Tags: updates, downloads, secure-boot

I'm running 22.04.2 LTS, and I have a message in the Software Update tool it says I have a firmware upgrade to install: "Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update" (Version 77 -> 217).

Whenever I try and do this using the GUI, it hangs and I'm then unable to shut down my machine. I have tried some basic terminal instructions, with similar effect.

Why am I unable to update the "Secure Boot dbx Configuration Update"?

Running `sudo fwupdate -l` gives the following:

`failed: Error opening file /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/FWUPDATE_DEBUG_LOG-0abba7dc-e516-4167-bbf5-4d9d1c739416: No such file or directory`

Running `sudo fwupdate -i` gives the following:

`(fwupdate:19008): FuPluginUefiCapsule-WARNING **: 17:06:18.722: SMBIOS BIOS Characteristics Extension Byte 2 is invalid -- UEFI Specification is unsupported, but /sys/firmware/efi exists: System does not support UEFI mode Information for the update status entry 0: Firmware GUID: {ffd4675e-ff47-46d9-ac24-8b331f937737} Update Status: No update info found`

Comment: Posts from ChatGPT are not allowed at SE sites.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add output of `sudo fwupdate -L; sudo fwupdate -i` command.

Comment: Off-Topic: @Pilot6, how do you determine ChatGPT being used here?

Comment: @richbl Look into edit history ;-) I removed it. That was a complete crap. Now it is a good question ;-)

Comment: Question updated with the requested outputs.

Comment: What does `sudo fwupdate -l` show? I think you didn't wait till the update finishes and turned off the PC. Let's see that output and also try `sudo fwupdate -a`. If it doesn't work, it is better to upgrade BIOS instead of using Ubuntu for that.

Comment: `sudo fwupdate -l` gives the following output:

`(fwupdate:20117): FuPluginUefiCapsule-WARNING **: 17:21:29.964: SMBIOS BIOS Characteristics Extension Byte 2 is invalid -- UEFI Specification is unsupported, but /sys/firmware/efi exists: System does not support UEFI mode
system-firmware type, {ffd4675e-ff47-46d9-ac24-8b331f937737} version 1444163667 can be updated to any version above 1380122623`

I tried `sudo fwupdate -a` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are problems with `fwupdate`.

It could be that you started the update, didn't let it finish and restarted the PC.

Also there may be other problems. The best choice in this case is to download BIOS from the PC vendor site and upgrade it according to vendor's manuals.